# Passing a temporary stream object to a lambda function as part of an extraction expression

Tags: c++11

I have a function which needs to parse some arguments and several `if` clauses inside it need to perform similar actions. In order to reduce typing and help keep the code readable, I thought I'd use a lambda to encapsulate the recurring actions, but I'm having trouble finding sufficient info to determine whether I'm mistakenly invoking undefined behavior or what I need to do to actualize my approach.

Below is a simplified code snippet of what I have currently:

```
int foo(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Using ss = std::istringstream;

    auto sf = [&](ss&& stream) -> ss& {
        stream.exceptions(ss::failbit);
        return stream;
    };

    int retVal = 0;

    bool valA = false;
    bool valB = false;

    try
    {
        for(int i=1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            std::string arg( argv[i] );

            if( !valA )
            {
                valA = true;
                sf( ss(arg) ) >> myInt;
            }
            else
            if( !valB )
            {
                valB = true;
                sf( ss(arg) ) >> std::hex >> myOtherInt;
            }
        }
    }
    catch( std::exception& err )
    {
        retVal = -1;
        std::cerr << err.what() << std::endl;
    }
    
    return retVal;
}
```

First, based on what I've read, I don't think that specifying the lambda argument as an rvalue reference (`ss&&`) is doing quite what I want it to do, however, trying to compile with it declared as a normal reference (`ss&`) failed with the error `cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'ss&'`. Changing `ss&` to `ss&&` got rid of the error and did not produce any warnings, but I'm not convinced that I'm using that construct correctly.

I've tried reading up on the various definitions for each, but the wording is a bit confusing.

I guess ultimately my questions are:

1. Can I expect the lifetime of my temporary `ss(arg)` object to extend through the entire extraction expression?
2. What is the correct way to define a lambda such that I can use the lambda in the way I demonstrate above, assuming that such a thing is actually possible?

Comment: Do you really need to keep setting `stream.exceptions(ss::failbit);` or do you only need to do that once for the whole foo fn? The purpose of using a lambda is then removed.

Comment: You aren't using any other foo vars in your lambda, and are passing ss in as an argument anyway. Try writing this as just a normal function. Then go back and make it a lambda.

Comment: Your approach looks OK to me. The temporary is guaranteed to be destroyed at the end of the full expression; roughly, at the semicolon.